# VsCode Auto Keep Blank Between ?? Chracter

Tags: visual-studio-code

VsCode Auto Keep Blank Between ?? characters. Like;

```
new Group({ title, default: isDefault ?? false }).save()
```

After I just save file It's becoming to;

```
new Group({ title, default: isDefault ? ? false }).save()
```

So I'm getting error and I can't fix it. What can I do?

Comment: What language is this? Please add the tag for it. Have you installed any extensions recently?

Comment: This is javascript. No It was normal yesterday and I did not install any extension.

Comment: You should show your `eslintrc.json` - there are some version settings that could be important here.

Comment: @wjandrea question is important. You say its javascript, but is the editor language set to javascript too ? (see bottom right of vscode)

Answer (score 1):

Install a VSCode formatter extension other than the default one VSCode uses; ESLint is one of the most used formatted out there.

Comment: I'm already using it but not solved my problem. I suppose that is happening because of some settings

Comment: Can you explain why one should not use VSC default formatter ? Especially, why it may solve the issue ? Maybe eslint is better, but it does not mean the default one is not doing the job